# What's the difference between testing an optional for "nil" and ".None"?

Tags: ios, swift, optional-values

I see everywhere in swift language, people testing for optional values with if statements so they can safely force unwrap, in 2 ways:

```
if optionalValue != .None {   

... some code ...

}
```

or

```
if optionalValue != nil {   

... some code ...

}
```

What's the difference and can it somehow influence my app/code in any way?
What's better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In normal usage there's no difference, they are interchangeable. `.None` is an enum representation of the `nil` (absence of) value implemented by the `Optional<T>` enum.

The equivalence of `.None` and `nil` is thanks to the `Optional<T>` type implementing the `NilLiteralConvertible` protocol, and an overload of the `!=` and `==` operators.

You can implement that protocol in your own classes/structs/enums if you want nil to be assignable, such as:

```
struct MyStruct : NilLiteralConvertible {
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> MyStruct {
        return MyStruct() // <== here you should provide your own implementation
    }
}

var t: MyStruct = nil
```

(note that the variable is not declared as optional)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is readily available if you command-click on the word `.None`. Here is what the Swift package reveals:

```
enum Optional<T> : Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    init()
    init(_ some: T)

    /// Haskell's fmap, which was mis-named
    func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
    func getMirror() -> MirrorType
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> T?
}
```

So in most cases you can use either because optional values should conform to the protocol `NilLiteralConvertible` (although I am not sure about this last point).

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, as `.none` (basically it's `Optional.none`) and `nil` are equivalent to each other.

In fact, this statement run in playground then it's outputs is `true`:

```
nil == .none || print(nil == .none) -> true
```

The use of `nil` is more common and is the recommended convention.