# How am I getting nil from a variable with a default get

Tags: swift

My crash logs show that I have 25 crashes from the below code where I pass a variable `localTaskObject.recurringBase` into a switch statement where the variable has a default value. How is it possible to get a nil from a variable where the get has a default of `return .none`?

Switch statement where the nil crash occurs for :

```
switch localTaskObject.recurringBase {
    case .weekly:
        pickerView.selectRow((components.weekday ?? 1) - 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    case .monthly:
        pickerView.selectRow((components.day ?? 1) - 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    case .yearly:
        pickerView.selectRow((components.month ?? 1) - 1, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
        pickerView.selectRow((components.day ?? 1) - 1, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
    default:
        break
}
```

The 'recurringBase' is set here:

```
@objc(Task)  
public class Task: NSManagedObject {
... // Other code
  var recurringBase : RecurringBase {
    set {
        let toSet = newValue.rawValue
        if toSet != primitiveValue(forKey: keyRecurringBase) as? String {
            willChangeValue(forKey: keyRecurringBase )
            setPrimitiveValue(toSet, forKey: keyRecurringBase)
            didChangeValue(forKey: keyRecurringBase)
        }
    }
    get {
        if let storedString = primitiveValue(forKey: keyRecurringBase) as? String, let recurring = RecurringBase(rawValue: storedString) {
            return recurring
        }
        return .none
    }
  }
}
```

Image of error:
[image: Shows crash log where nil was found]

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with `localTaskObject` and not `recurringBase`. Is it declared as implicitly unwrapped? Are you sure it has a value?

Comment: Also, you seem to have loaded the crash log with a different version of the code. Note that the highlighted line is a blank line. Are you sure the crash is really on the `switch` line?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59346112/13944750) may help you about what is .none

Comment: The error message implies that you have an issue with a property that is declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional (using !) so you might be looking in the wrong place as @HangarRash points out above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.none` was equal to `nil`
I changed the function to make the recurring base an optional, forcing my other statements to always then safely unwrap it. I also changed my if-then checks to explicitly look for nil instead of .none, to make the code clearer.

Thanks!